# How do I get additional information from ReflectPermission?

Tags: java, reflection, private, securitymanager

I would like to know the exact field or method that a class tries to access via reflection. As far as I know, the JVM asks for a ReflectPermission when a class tries to access non public fields or methods.

Comment: i know that it is not nice to push, but seriously, someone should have an idea ;)